# Train-Valid-Test split for custom dataset using PyTorch and TorchVision

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I have some image data for a binary classification task and the images are organised into 2 folders as data/model_data/class-A and data/model_data/class-B.

There are a total of N images. I want to have a 70/20/10 split for train/val/test. 
I am using PyTorch and Torchvision for the task. Here is the code I have so far.

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms, utils, datasets, models

data_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

model_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root, transform=data_transform) 
train_count = int(0.7 * total_count) 
valid_count = int(0.2 * total_count)
test_count = total_count - train_count - valid_count
train_dataset, valid_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(model_dataset, (train_count, valid_count, test_count))
train_dataset_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=NUM_WORKER)  
valid_dataset_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valid_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=NUM_WORKER) 
test_dataset_loader  = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset , batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False,num_workers=NUM_WORKER)
dataloaders = {'train': train_dataset_loader, 'val': valid_dataset_loader, 'test': test_dataset_loader}
```

I feel that this isn't the correct way to be doing this because of 2 reasons.

- I am applying the same transform to all the splits. (This is not what I want to do, obviously! The solution for this is most probably the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539790/11009359).)
- Usually people first separate the original data into test/train and then they
  separate train  into train/val, whereas I am directly separating the
  original data into train/val/test. (Is this correct?)

So, my question is, is what I am doing correct? (Probably not) 
And if it is not correct, how do I go about writing the data loaders to achieve the required splits, so that I can apply separate transforms to each of train/test/val?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Usually people first separate the original data into test/train and
>   then they separate train into train/val, whereas I am directly
>   separating the original data into train/val/test. (Is this correct?)

Yes, it's fully correct, readable and totally fine all in all

> I am applying the same transform to all the splits. (This is not what
>   I want to do, obviously! The solution for this is most probably the
>   answer here.)

Yes, that answer is a possibility but it's pointlessly verbose tbh. You can use third party tool [**torchdata**](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchdata), simply instalable with:

```
pip install torchdata
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://szymonmaszke.github.io/torchdata/index.html) (also disclaimer: I'm the author).

It allows you to map your transformations to any `torch.utils.data.Dataset` easily (in this case to `train`). Your code would look like that (only two lines have to change, check the comments, also formatted your code to follow it easier):

```
import torch
import torchvision

import torchdata as td

data_transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose(
    [
        torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        torchvision.transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
        torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
            mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
        ),
    ]
)

# Single change, makes an instance of torchdata.Dataset
# Works just like PyTorch's torch.utils.data.Dataset, but has
# additional capabilities like .map, cache etc., see project's description
model_dataset = td.datasets.WrapDataset(torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root))
# Also you shouldn't use transforms here but below
train_count = int(0.7 * total_count)
valid_count = int(0.2 * total_count)
test_count = total_count - train_count - valid_count
train_dataset, valid_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(
    model_dataset, (train_count, valid_count, test_count)
)

# Apply transformations here only for train dataset

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(data_transform)

# Rest of the code goes the same

train_dataset_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=NUM_WORKER
)
valid_dataset_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    valid_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=NUM_WORKER
)
test_dataset_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    test_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False, num_workers=NUM_WORKER
)
dataloaders = {
    "train": train_dataset_loader,
    "val": valid_dataset_loader,
    "test": test_dataset_loader,
}
```

And yeah, I agree that specifying `transform` before splitting isn't too clear and IMO this is way more readable.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful.

Comment: I get `class conflict` error when I import torchdata. do you know what is the problem?